# Running a Command in xterm Without the Window Closing

Tags: unix, script, xterm

I am trying to figure out how to open an xterm and execute a command in the new window without the window closing.  Ideally, I would like to be able to open an xterm, switch users, and source a .cshrc file. Something like:

```
xterm -e "su - user2; source /home/user/.cshrc"
```

I have read that a -hold option does this, but -hold does not seem to be supported by my machines.  The different commands I have tried either close the screen immediately or give a "execvp" error.  I have tried to implement it in a script as well, but as soon as the script is done executing it closes.  Any ideas?  Thanks!